# C++ decimal checking if statement errors?

Tags: c++, if-statement, casting

I'm doing some homework for a C++ class, and i'm pretty new to C++. I've run into some issues with my if statement... What i'm doing, is i have the user input a time, between 0.00 and 23.59. the : is replaced by a period btw. that part works. i then am seperating the hour and the minute, and checking them to make sure that they are in valid restraints. checking the hour works, but not the minute... heres my code:

```
minute= startTime - static_cast<int>(startTime);
hour= static_cast<int>(startTime);

//check validity
if (minute > 0.59) {
    cout << "ERROR! ENTERED INVALID TIME! SHUTTING DOWN..." << endl;;
    return(0);
}
if (hour > 23) {
    cout << "ERROR! ENTERED INVALID TIME! SHUTTING DOWN..." << endl;;
    return(0);
}
```

again, the hour works if i enter 23, but if i enter 23.59, i get the error, but if i enter 23.01 i do not. also, if i enter 0.59 it also gives the error, but not 0.58. I tried switching the `if(minute > 0.59)` to `if(minute > 0.6)` but for some reason that caused problems elsewhere. i am at a complete loss as to what to do, so any help would be great! thanks a million!

**EDIT:** i just entered 0.58, and it didnt give me the error... but if i make it a 1.59 it gives an error again... also, upvotes would be nice :D

Comment: Use `double`, not `int`.

Comment: Please note that the `homework` tag is deprecated.

Comment: sorry, i typed it wrong. please look at it again :D

Comment: Simply put. Don't use floating point numbers for time calculations. Store the minutes and hours in seperate `int` variables.

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: alright, i see what you mean. that actually worked XD thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic (`float` and `double`) is inherently fuzzy. There are always some digits behind the decimal point that you don't see in the rounded representation that is sent to your stream, and comparisons can also be fuzzy because the representation you are used to (decimal) is not the one the computer uses (binary).

Represent a time as `int hours` and `int minutes`, and your problems will fade away. Most libraries measure time in ticks (usually seconds or microseconds) and do not offer sub-tick resolution. You do well to emulate them.

Comment: Always is a strong word.  I'll bet he won't have problems with `1.50` or `2.25`.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are only correct in 0.0000176% of all cases. I think "always" qualifies.

Comment: @MrLister - if you pick a random sequence of decimal digits that does not overflow when converted to `double`, the probability is 0 that you will have a value that can be represented exactly as a `double`.

Comment: Just as a matter of discourse, I wouldn't describe floating-point arithmetic as "fuzzy". It's well defined and reproducible. As you say, it's thinking in decimal that leads to misunderstandings. That is, it's the **analogy** between decimal numbers and floating-point numbers (assuming a binary floating-point representation) that's fuzzy.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's just not true. But any representation has `some` values that can be represented exactly (even decimal). But even decimal can not represent all values exactly. Try representing 1/3 exactly in decimal. I believe "small talk" (but memory is fuzzy from classes so many years ago) used an exact representation by keeping floats as two integers ('numerator' and a 'denominator').

Comment: @LokiAstari - yes, it's true. There are an infinite number of decimal value representations that will not overflow a `double` and only a finite number that are exactly representable. So if you choose a decimal value at random, the chances of getting one that's representable are *(some large, finite number)/infinity*. That's 0. This is a slightly weakened version of a statement that a math professor of mine once made: if you choose the coefficients for a Taylor series at random, with probability 1 you will not get an analytic function; but it's only the analytic functions that are interesting.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes by that argument you are correct. But the same argument can be made for any representation (including decimal). There are an infinite number of real numbers. Only a finite number can be represented by decimal representation. Thus the probability of a random real number being represented in decimal representation is 0. So not a real useful argument.

Comment: And there are infinite integral numbers, only a finite number of which are representable in our computer `int` types. Ergo, since finite/infinite is 0, you can represent a random integer number in a computer with probability 0. Yet we're doing fine with our limited computers!

Comment: @MrLister - yes, if you drop the requirement that I stated, that the value does not overflow. That's the key difference between integer types and floating-point types: a value of type `int` corresponds to exactly one whole number; a value of type `double` corresponds to an infinite set of real numbers.

Comment: @LokiAstari - I wasn't presenting an argument, just an observation.

Comment: @PeteBecker And this is where we differ. A double number does not "correspond to" other real numbers. It only has one value, which is close, but not identical, to other real values in the same range. The double number 1.0 does NOT "represent" 0.999999999999999999999999.

Comment: @MrLister -I was very careful **not** say that 1.0 **represents** 0.9999 whatever. That's why I used the fuzzy term "correspond to". The point is that you **cannot** treat floating-point values as analogs to real numbers, precisely because there are an infinite number of real numbers for every floating-point value. But it's perfectly meaningful to partition real numbers into equivalence classes based on whether they map into the same `double` value (i.e. their values are closer to that `double` value than to either of its neighbors). It's in that sense that `double` values correspond to reals.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of floating point numbers is prone to failure, because very few of them can be represented exactly in base 2. There's always going to be some possibility that two different numbers are going to round in different directions.

The simplest fix is to add a very tiny fudge factor to the number you're comparing:

```
if (minute > 0.59 + epsilon)
```

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't, ever, use double (nor float) to store two integer values using the integer and decimal part as separator. The decimal data types are not precise enough, so you may have wrong results (in case of a round).

A good solution in your case is either to use a struct (or a pair) or even an integer.

With integer, you can use mod or div of multiples of then to extract the real value. Example:

```
int startTime = 2359;
int hour = startTime / 100;
int minute = startTime % 100;
```

Although, with struct the code would look simpler and easier to understand (and to maintain).

Comment: I'd agree with your first sentence, but it representing type as the number of days since some epoque in a `double`, with the fractional part being used for the time, seems rather common.  (I'm not saying that it's a good idea, but that it's widespread.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: AFAIK, when representing from some epoch, the decimal part is, in general, used to represent only milliseconds (or micro), which, in most cases, is a bearable approximation.

Comment: Not in Excel.  I've worked on Excel plugins, and the time comes in as a double, representing the number of _days_ (and fractional days) from 1 Jan. 1900.  Probably because of the influence of Excel, this format seems to be widespread in some milieu.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can compare to exactly `0.59`; this value
cannot be represented in the machine.  You're comparing
something which is very close to `0.59` with something else that
is very close to `0.59`.

Personally, I wouldn't input time this way at all.  A much
better solution would be to learn how to use `std::istream` to
read the value.  But if you insist, and you have `startTime` as
your `double`, you need to multiply it by `100.0` (so that all
of the values that interest you are integers, and can be 
represented exactly), then round it, then convert it to an
integer, and use the modulo and division operators *on the
integer* to extract your values.  Something along the lines of:

```
assert( startTime >= 0.0 && startTime <= 24.0 );
int tmpTime = 100.0 * startTime + 0.5;
int minute = tmpTime % 100;
int hour = tmpTime / 100;
```

When dealing with integral values, it's much simpler to use
integral types.